# I would like to update my chat table notification column. But it seems like I have a wrong ajax script or php script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ajax Code where I want to submit my empid and ownid to markread.php to use as a $_POST['empid']; and $_POST['ownid'];

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){    
       $(".chatlist").click(function(){
           var name = $(this).data('fullname');
           var empid = $(this).data('employeeid');
           var ownid = $('#yourownemployeeid').val();

           $.post('chat/markread.php', {empid: empid,ownid: ownid}, function(){
              //majority of code here...
           });    
       });
    });
</script>
```

Php Code

```
<?php

    include("../connection.php"); 
    $id = $_GET['empid'];
    $id2 = $_GET['ownid'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE chat SET notification = 'Seen'  WHERE recievernumber = '$id' and senderenumber = '$id2'");

?>
```

Comment: `$id = $_POST['empid'];$id2 = $_POST['ownid'];` and  `$.post('chat/markread.php', {"empid": empid,"ownid": ownid}, function(){`. two changes and you have done

Comment: Three things. 1. You're posting the data while you use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` to fetch the data. 2. You are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions ... **you really shouldn't**. 3. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: check and let us know

Comment: @Anant still not working.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can you tell me what to do to prevent sql injections?

Comment: You should start by not using `mysql_`-functions. Use Mysqli or PDO instead (read the PHP doc) and then use Prepared Statements (also in the PHP-doc). You can read more about SQL injections here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thanks! @MagnusEriksson just new in learning php ajax languages.

Comment: Ajax isn't a language. It's a way to send http requests, using the Javascript-language ;-)

Comment: lol sorry bout that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson <?php
 define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
 define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
 define('DB_DATABASE', 'portal');
 $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
 
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
?> is this correct? this is what I'm using right now.

Comment: Test it and see what happens?

Comment: It works well for me. Does this prevent sql injections?